# Flex on salesforce sites error

Tags: apache-flex, authentication, salesforce, sites

I have a simple logic on flex to login to salesforce and create a record. The flex swf when embedded on VF page works fine internal to salesforce. But my requirement is to display the flex on site page to create record. The login fails on the same page when accessed through public sites. Any help is very appreciated.

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import com.salesforce.*;
    import com.salesforce.objects.*;
    import com.salesforce.results.*;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
        import com.salesforce.AsyncResponder;
        import com.salesforce.events.ApexFaultEvent;
        import com.salesforce.objects.LoginRequest;
        import com.salesforce.objects.SObject;
        import com.salesforce.results.Fault;
        import com.salesforce.results.LoginResult;
        import com.salesforce.results.QueryResult;
        import com.salesforce.results.UpsertResult;

    [Bindable] public var sfdc:Connection = new Connection();

    private function login():void {
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/crossdomain.xml");

        var lr:LoginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        sfdc.protocol = "https";
        sfdc.serverUrl = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/14.0";
    lr.username = "uname.com";
                           lr.password = "pwdsectoken"; 


        lr.callback = new AsyncResponder(loginSuccess, loginFault);


        sfdc.login(lr);

    }

    private function submitForm():void {

        var aSo:Array = new Array();
        var so:SObject = new SObject("Contact");
        so.FirstName = firstName.text;
        so.LastName = lastName.text;
        so.Email = email.text;

        aSo.push(so);

        sfdc.create(aSo,
            new AsyncResponder(
                function (obj:Object):void {
                    if (obj[0].success == true) {
                        Alert.show("Created record: "+obj[0].id);
                    } else {
                        Alert.show(obj[0].errors[0].message)
                    }
                }, sfdcFailure
            )
        );

    }

    private function loginSuccess(result:Object):void {
         Alert.show("Done");
        contactForm.enabled = true;
    }

    private function sfdcFailure(fault:Object):void {
        Alert.show(fault.faultstring);
    }

    private function loginFault(fault:Object):void
    {
        Alert.show("Could not log into SFDC: "+fault.fault.faultString,"Login Error");
        Alert.show("error " + fault.fault.faultDetail);
    }

]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Text text="To create a new Contact, Last Name is required by Salesforce.com while Email is required via a custom validation rule. &#xd;&#xd;Submit the form with different combinations to view the resulting messages returned from Salesforce.com.&#xd;" width="449"/>
<mx:Form id="contactForm" width="100%" height="100%" enabled="false">
    <mx:FormItem label="First Name">
        <mx:TextInput id="firstName"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Last Name">
        <mx:TextInput id="lastName"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Email">
        <mx:TextInput id="email"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem>
        <mx:Button label="Submit" click="submitForm()"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Am I doing anything wrong. I have placed crossdeomain.xml in bin /libs / html template folder. Is there any remote site setting required?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex and Salesforce connection: NOT ABLE TO login from flex to salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371755/flex-and-salesforce-connection-not-able-to-login-from-flex-to-salesforce)

Comment: Error is security error accessing url